# Data is not being saved in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save data, but on submitting the data, it just refreshes the page, but not actually stores data in table. and even it is not giving any errors too. What I want to do is after saving data, control should come on same page with empty textboxes.

Using Ruby 2.4.1, Rails 5.1.3, sqLite3

This is content of feedback_controller.rb

```
class FeedbackController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
     redirect_to root_path

     respond_to do |f|
      if @feedback.save
         f.html {redirect_to @feedback, notice: 'feedback submitted'}
         f.json {render :new, status: :created, location: :@feedback}
     else
         f.html {render :new }
         f.json {render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
     end
    end
  end

  private

   #  def set_feedback
   #    @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
   #  end

   def feedback_params
     params.require(:feedback).permit(:name, :email, :message)
   end
  end
```

And here is new.html.erb file.

```
<%= form_with scope: :feedback, url: feedback_new_path, local: true do |form| %>

 <% if @feedback.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(feedback.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feedback from being saved:</h2>

       <ul>
         <% @feedback.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :feedback_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, id: :feedback_email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :message %>
    <%= form.text_area :message, id: :feedback_message %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Submit Feedback"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
```

This is what puma server saying on log while storing data:

```
Started POST "/feedback/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-14 21:33:41 +0530
Processing by FeedbackController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Dk1sGiKYryIOeU6HyO7zeX6wqXazj9BUfooJgIDH1JjHxuKwA5MT0E6zvuwFYXGA8xEOz+tGAiXWySKv7voKvg==", "feedback"=>{"name"=>"sheshang", "email"=>"sid@gm.co", "message"=>"this is demo message"}, "commit"=>"Submit Feedback"}
  Rendering feedback/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered feedback/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 55.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

---

In addition to this problem, I want to know that how to debug in rails app. Like in C or any other program we used to put printf statements to check whether the control is going inside or not. How we can do in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, you're posting to the `new` action:

```
Started POST "/feedback/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-14 21:33:41 +0530
Processing by FeedbackController#new as HTML
```

But the `new` action doesn't do a save.

So, you probably want:

```
<%= form_with scope: :feedback, url: feedbacks_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

By convention, if you do (in your `routes.rb` file):

```
resources :feedbacks
```

then you should get:

```
    feedbacks   GET        /feedbacks(.:format)              feedbacks#index
                POST       /feedbacks(.:format)              feedbacks#create
 new_feedback   GET        /feedbacks/new(.:format)          feedbacks#new
edit_feedback   GET        /feedbacks/:id/edit(.:format)     feedbacks#edit
     feedback   GET        /feedbacks/:id(.:format)          feedbacks#show
                PATCH      /feedbacks/:id(.:format)          feedbacks#update
                PUT        /feedbacks/:id(.:format)          feedbacks#update
                DELETE     /feedbacks/:id(.:format)          feedbacks#destroy
```

As you can see, this does not generate a `POST` verb for the `new` action, which suggests that you're not using conventional routes. If that is true, then you may need to update your routes so that you get `feedbacks_path`.

I recommend following convention as it often makes life easier.

As far as printing to console, I tend to do:

```
puts "#{self.class}.#{__method__}, var: #{var}"
```

I replace `var` with whatever variable I want to inspect. I like to include the `#{self.class}.#{__method__}` bit because it let's me know which class and method I'm in.

Comment: I am a new learner to this tech. So I don't know specifically that what should I have, feedback or feedbacks. Suppose I added resources :feedbacks in my routes.rb. Then what?

Comment: Did you update your `form_with` as I suggested? With what result?

Comment: yes i did updated. and i am getting some dependent errors which I think i can solve. Let me do that. I will let you know later

Comment: Thanks. Finally data is being saved. There were some dependent errors after your solution. But now it's working properly.

Comment: Yay! Good luck on your project.